# Short story collection published 1988-1995

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

A library patron is trying to identify a short story collection she bought in the late 1980s - mid 1990s. Some of the stories she remembers:

- A candlemaker who at first hoards his candles but then learns to share
- A pagan stoneworker superstitious about working on a Christian statue. He gouges the statue's eyes out and causes his own death.
- A man who one day finds his journal entries written in blood and realizes a doppelganger is invading his body.

Comment: Can your patron include any more information? Such as any more plot details? Anything about the cover? Anything - gender, nationality, etc - about the author(s)? *Any* small detail can be helpful - there's a checklist halfway don [this page](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tags/story-identification/info) that may be helpful :)

Comment: Thanks. I'll add to my post if I find out more.

Comment: Here's someone else looking for it: https://www.reddit.com/r/tipofmytongue/comments/1rt9wz/tomt_book_collection_of_dark_fantasy_short/